# Haskell use input as operator

Tags: haskell

how do i use the input as an operator?
this is my code:

```
applyOperator :: IO()
applyOperator = do
 putStrLn "Input first Integer: "
 num1 <- getLine
 putStrLn "Input operator: "
 op <- getLine
 putStrLn "Input second Integer: "
 num2 <- getLine
 let solution = (read op :: Num) num1 num2
 putStrLn solution
```

ghci gives me this error:

```
   * Expecting one more argument to `Num'
      Expected a type, but `Num' has kind `* -> Constraint'
    * In an expression type signature: Num
      In the expression: read op :: Num
      In the expression: (read op :: Num) num1 num2
```

i dont really know what ghci is trying to tell me with that.

i've also tried to write line 9 like this:

```
let solution = num1 ´(read op :: Num)´ num2
```

is it wrong to try to convert `op` to the `Num` type? is `op` a string when i use `<- getLine`?

thank you

Comment: `Num` is a typeclass, not a type, hence `read op :: Num` makes not much sense. Furthermore parsing to a function is not possible. You can work with a lookup table for example where you map `"+"` to `(+)`, etc.

Comment: `read` returns something with a `Read` instance. Unless there is a `Read` instance of `Num a => a -> a -> a`, you can't use `read` like this. (Theoretically, you *could* write such an instance yourself, but as an orphaned instance--one not defined in either the module where the type class is defined or in the module where the type is defined--it's not considered a good idea.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Num` is a typeclass, not a type, hence `read op :: Num` makes not much sense.

Furthermore, parsing to a function is not possible, so if you use `read op :: Int -> Int`, that will not work either.

You can work with a lookup table for example where you map `"+"` to `(+)`, etc.:

```
parseFunc :: String -> Int -> Int -> Int
parseFunc "+" = (+)
parseFunc "-" = (-)
parseFunc "*" = (*)
```

then for the reader we use:

```
applyOperator :: IO()
applyOperator = do
  putStrLn "Input first Integer: "
  num1 <- readLn
  putStrLn "Input operator: "
  op <- getLine
  putStrLn "Input second Integer: "
  num2 <- readLn
  let solution = parseFunc op num1 num2
  print solution
```

Comment: @aaliyah: you can also use `print solution`, `print = putStrLn . show`.